# Adaptive subdivision surface UV reflection problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers

I need a help. I tried to make a wire mesh rope with UV and subsurf but there was something wrong with the reflection.

As you can see, after rendering, it looks like the reflection is changed in the middle of UV map:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the UV map and nodes:

[image]
[image]

Here is the modifier:

[image]

Anyone who knows why this happens? How can I have the right reflection on the surface?

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours more, i got what i wanted finally.
only what i did was cut off the area causing problem. ^^
- cut off UV texture
- cut off faces

But i still wonder why.

[image]

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that there seems to be 2 uvs on stage. perhaps the problem of adding a common texture coordinate for 2 image textures in the scene can be solved. but I'm not so sure.[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer. but it doesn't work to this problem. ^^;